# How to sync android market account if I have the app but the market isn't in my add account?

Tags: google-play-store, accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device)

I've been trying to get the new market on my phone for a while, I finally did then it asked if i wanted to add an account, i clicked yes. Once i went to settings to add the account market account wasn't in there, how do i add one now?

Comment: So are you saying the account is gone from your phone completely, or it's in your settings but the Market won't let you use it?

Comment: It never was there, i downloaded the android market from the internet and when i went to add an account the option to add market isn't there

Comment: Do you mean you're looking for a separate "Market" account type in the settings? Market accounts are just Google accounts, there isn't a separate type for them.

Comment: how do i make the google account then?

Comment: `Settings->Accounts and Sync->"Add Account" button`

Comment: What account do i add?

Comment: Because I don't have the gmail account option there either, i only have exchange active sync (which i already have made), facebook, htc sense, htc sense QQ, HTC sense Qzong, HTC Sense Tencent Weibo and Mail?

Comment: Oh. Do you live in China? I'm not even sure if you can set up a Google account on Android devices without rooting your phone and installing a completely custom firmware ([related forum thread here](http://androidforums.com/sony-ericsson-xperia-ray/406633-cant-add-google-account-china.html))

Comment: oh my god this is so annoying /: Why does all technology have to have problems in China?!

Comment: It says I can do this if i download european software, android 2.3.4 Gingerbread but how do i get this on htc cha cha?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know anything about the ChaCha or how to do that :-/ You could re-word this question to ask for help with that (or just add that detail), though, since it does seem to be the underlying issue.