# Bought a cheap android tablet, how can I install GMail, Play Store and the other Google apps?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-apps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device)

I met the IFA here in Berlin on the last day. This was a great chance to buy one of these simple cheap chinese no-name tablets. I wondered, a smallweight tablet with HDMI, Bluetooth, hd display and a dualcore! cpu. I got it for 70 €. But at home i surprised, ohhh, no Market, no Gmail. Tried different ways to install these apps. Every time force close.

I'm using Ubuntu as my workstation and looked with adb for the device. Found one, good! The command lsusb gives me

```
Bus 001 Device 031: ID 18d1:4e22 Google Inc. Nexus S (debug)
```

And now, i would like to install google apps like market and gmail. For this i've downloaded the [gapps](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/44361651/gapps_ics_4.0.3_v7.zip) zip file. No chance to install one of this apk files after unzipping. Does anyone have an idea how i can achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this tablet is stock. So there is neither root, nor nandroid or similiar. I have no idea how to mount the correspondent partition as read write without root access. So its not possible to install clockworkmod and the google apps over the zip.