# How can I create a Google Account?

Tags: google-account, google-drive

I have a new Android 4.0 device ([d2pad](http://d2pad.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=frontpage&Itemid=203)), and I have installed Google Drive and Google+ but neither one works.  When I try to start Google Drive it gives me the message "No Google account found, exiting".  I poked around and tried to find where to create a Google account, but on the account screen I don't see a Google option.  How can I create a Google account, or what do I need to install to create one?

I see the following options on the add account screen:

- Facebook
- Corporate
- Email
- Dropbox

Corrective actions tried:

- Installing "Google Play Services" from the marketplace.
- Resetting to factory defaults
- Installing "Google Play Services" again

I also can't log into Google for my marketplace login.

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: Perhaps, more importantly, who is your carrier?

Comment: @AlEverett No carrier.

Comment: @Martyn cheapo [d2pad](http://d2pad.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=frontpage&Itemid=203).

Comment: I did some research and kept running across "Google Service Framework", but I can't see how to install that.

Comment: Probably related: [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, ...) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the hardware you have bought isn't an official Android device, and so won't have google account options available to you.  I'll try and find a work around for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a D2pad as well and I am successfully using google+. like Mike C said, go to Settings>accounts&sync>add account (top right corner). There will be 4 options to choose from. Corporate/DropboX/Email/Google. Tap google and sign in to your google account. now that you setup your google account, open 1mobile market search and download and install google+. Hope this helps

Comment: OP already said that they have no "Google" option on the account creation screen.

Comment: Yeah, I have Facebook instead of Google.  Considering a factory reset ...

Comment: I just did a factory reset and still don't have a Google account option. :-(

Comment: there's a firmware update if you go to d2pad's website. http://d2pad.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=173&Itemid=208. hope that helps

Comment: @Danny Thanks, but no apparent change...

Answer (score -1):

Once you have an active Google account, which you can create here

https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&hl=en

On your Android ICS device, go to:

Settings>Accounts>Add Account

you'll see many options from which you can choose, among them Google.

Generally you can add an account by running a google app, such as reader, play or gmail, and it will ask you to sign in with your google account.

Comment: Sorry Mike, I don't see an "Google" option on the account screen.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your device isn't approved by Google, so sadly, you can't officially get Google apps for it. It also seems to be a pretty unknown tablet from an unknown manufacturer, so there isn't a community around it who might have unofficial versions.

However, *if* the tablet is just a rebadged version of something more popular (like many of these tablets are), [this](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) program might help you identify the actual manufacturer and get help that way.

Comment: Answers should stand on their own. It looks like the best part of this answer is behind that link you left.

Comment: Alright, I've edited it to point directly to the program now.

Answer (score -1):

some people have found work arounds for this problem. i haven't tried myself but it looks like there are 2 ways it can be done. here is the linkhttp://www.androidtablets.net/forum/allwinner-a10-based/47980-can-anyone-help-me.html

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please [avoid answers that only contain a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/164138) because your answer becomes useless if the link is broken.
It would be best if you include the essential parts in your answer and provide the link for reference.