# Where to download and install Google Apps on Android 4.0.4 device?

Tags: applications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-store, apk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device)

I have an international android smartphone which doesn't have anything related to Google Play Store installed. So I have to install  GoogleLoginService.apk, GoogleServicesFramework.apk, Vending.apk, ... by myself. I was able to find information about how to do it online but I cannot find where to get those apks for my version of Android, which is version 4.0.4.

If I download them, how can I know/verify they are the right version for the android 4.0.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to flash GAPPS (Google Apps) ZIP. [Click here](http://goo-inside.me/gapps/gapps-gb-20110828-signed.zip) to download GAPPS for ICS. For alternate links or other gapps versions see [this link](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Latest_Version#Google_Apps).