# Google Play Store - Not Working

Tags: google-play-store, arnova-gbook

I'm currently using an Arnova 10G2 that has never been used as it was a relatives christmas present. When trying to load the Google Play Store on the device after re-downloading it from Softpedia, a notification comes up saying:

> You must add an account to continue. Do you want to add one now?

Whether I click yes or no, it closes the application and brings me back to the devices home screen. I do not want to root the device to fix this.

Is there any sort of known solution? I could not see a clear one when searching.

Comment: `I do not want to root the device to fix this.` - Unfortunately, you probably have to. See [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, ...) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808)