# How to get Google Play in China

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I just bought the Samsung S3 in China and Google Play is not installed - how can I get it, or at least get my Gmail?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, ...) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808)

Comment: ^ this also requires [root and custom recovery](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2092244) to flash the google apps zip. Also, in order to access the play store server, you will need a VPN service to bypass the *Great Firewall of China*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know it works or not. I just Googled and found this [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=26409760).

According to the link you might want to use VPN services which changes your IP to other country IP which is valid in Google Play and also according to comment on same link one has changed his OS to Hongkong OS(i.e Google Play available OS).

You might want to go through LINK once. Hope this might be helpful for you!