# How can I root my Yarvik Tab411?

Tags: rooting

How can I root my tablet, the [yarvik tab411](http://www.yarvik.com/en/products/tablets/tablets_10/Tab411/)? I tried to find information on the internet, but had no success.

The tab runs Android <del>4.1.1</del><sup>1</sup> 2.3.3.

<sup>1</sup> according to the link, this device currently ships with Android 4.1.1. Marrssel has an older version, running 2.3.3. <sup>(comment by Izzy)</sup>

Comment: Generally it helps to provide a few more details: e.g. a link to technical specs of the device, mentioning which Android version it runs, etc. Also, reading the tag info (hover your mouse over the 'rooting' tag) should have given you some start, and e.g. pointed to our [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) -- where I cannot find your device being added. Nevertheless, you could check there whether one of the methods sounds promising.

Comment: I updated your question with some more details (please check if they are correct). I also removed your second question from this post (one question per post!), you can check [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575) meanwhile for details on that.

Answer (score 1):

According to a thread in the [yarvik forum](http://forum.yarvik.com/showthread.php?2748-De-Tab411-rooten) (besides, the first hit on a Google search for [yarvik tab411 root](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=yarvik+tab411+root)), you should be able to use the *SuperOneClick* tool. But while the name suggests "one click" should be pretty easy, it might be not the case.

However, you will need to:

- download SuperOneClick e.g. from [here](http://tabletrepublic.com/forum/android-hacking-tweaking/how-root-tablet-superoneclick-3131.html)
- download and install the device drivers (for your device, possibly to be found on the yarvik's support pages) on your Windows machine
- activate *USB Debugging* on your device
- run the *SuperOneClick* application *as administrator* (oops) on Windows 7
- now the most difficult: click the "root" button :)

As I have no yarvik tablet, I could not check the above. It's just the result from a little Google search -- so forgive me in case it fails...

Comment: it works. I have anrdoid 2.3.3 (I forgot to mention ...sorry) and I download SuperOneClick 2.3.3 and....done!!!  thx for help!!!  have a nice day.

Comment: Glad it worked! You could mark this answer as "accepted" then (using the checkmark next to it) for other users to identify this as workable solution. Thanks!

Comment: This has a [section in our FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask), describing it including screenshots. "Accepting" is the last item in this section -- but of course the other hints are useful, too :)