# How to install Android Composite ADB Interface

Tags: rooting, adb, amazon-kindle-fire-hd

Having trouble with this line on [this tutorial](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/connect-adb.html):

> "In your Android SDK directory, at \extras\amazon\kindle_fire_usb_driver, run KindleDrivers.exe, and then follow the instructions on the screen."

I just cannot find this area, any idea where i should install it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On XDA, in the [user profile of Astarioth](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=4487518), there's a link mentioned in the "most thanked" tab:  https://dl.dropbox.com/s/vprplelu9zx7s2o/kindle_fire_usb_driver.rar?dl=1 (and this is the [XDA post thanked for](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=36033040)). The name of the `.rar` archive suggests it holds your wanted drivers -- and the quote

> [...] uninstall your old Kindle USB Driver and install this one.

confirms my guess :)

Now, why didn't you find it in your SDK directory, you might ask? Guess that's as it goes with apples and peaches. You assumed Google's Android SDK -- while Amazon has its own Android SDK. And that line most likely referred to the latter, while you have the former installed. Also only a guess -- but I'd say I guessed right again? You might want to read [Setting Up Your Development Environment](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/setup.html), take a special look at the section *Installing SDK Add-Ons*. If you work with Eclipse, this gives you another source to get to the Kindle drivers.

Comment: All i want is google play store :( thank you for your help.

Comment: Then you should not have bought a Kindle. Though running Android, they are competing Google. But that doesn't help you now -- what might help you is taking a look at [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575). I guess, rooting will always be the first step for that...

Comment: Okay thanks, I never bought it haha, Just a gift I am trying to make the most out of.

Comment: Oh -- OK, in that case my apologies for the accusation #D Have you checked the other [questions related to rooting the Kindle Fire HD](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-kindle-fire-hd+rooting)? They might provide additional help.