# Android Market or Google Play Store for black Pandigital Novel

Tags: google-play-store, pandigital-novel

I'm looking for an easy way to get the Android Market or Google Play Store on my black Pandigital novel. I've searched and searched, but I couldn't find any ways to get either of them. If anyone knows an easy, simple way, please let me know!

Comment: [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device)

Answer (score 0):

You can try and install the Google Play 4.1.10 [shared on droid-life](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/05/29/download-new-google-play-store-4-1-10/).

Comment: Don't forget: in order to install the Google Play app on a device which does not already have it, that device needs to be rooted and the app must be made a system app.