# Cannot add Google accounts on Huawei U8825D/G330D

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, huawei

This is a Huawei U8825D/G330D running Android 4.0.4 on a contract with China Unicom. I have used two Android phones in the past, and was always able to sync all my Google services by logging into a Google account on my Android, but I haven't been able to add a Google account on this Huawei phone.

I tried going to Settings > Accounts and Sync > Add an Account, but the only types of accounts available for adding in the menu are Huawei Cloud+, Company, Email, and Wandoujia (an app store service popular in China). There is no option to add a Google account. This doesn't only create the problem of not being able to sync Google services - without a Google account enabled on this phone, I cannot even open Google Play store, Gmail, and the like. I am able to install these apps on the phone, but when I click on them, a screen (of the background frame of, say, the Play store) would briefly show up before the app closing itself in a moment. I tried restoring the phone to factory settings but it has not worked.

Comment: Sounds like your device doesn't have Google's apps pre-installed. You'd want to take a look at the explanation in [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device) (which requires rooting the device).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- download the google play .apk using the built-in browser of your smartphone (browse the apk file)
- then, open google play and install gmail
- then, download Google Contacts Sync 4.4.2-1289630.apk using the built-in browser of your smartphone
- then go to your contacts menu option and then you will se that you can sign into the google account

Comment: Adding linkd to this would be useful.  I recommend [APK mirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/).

Answer (score 2):

This may be a late response but after finding the answer I thought I should publish it. If you have a Huawei phone that's been set up for the Chinese market then you'll find you cannot simply add a Google account.
First, using Huawei's own application manager, find Google's Play Store and install it. Once installed, use it to install Google's own YouTube app.
From YouTube you can sign in add any number of Google accounts.