# How to install Google Play Services?

Tags: google-play-services

In notification panel, I have a notification that says "Instal/update Google Play Services" (or so).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What app throws out the notification? Do you have the *Google Play* app installed on the device? If not, check out [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575)

Comment: Note that "Google Play Services" is not the same as "Google Apps Package". This is not a duplicate of "How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?"

Comment: Just tap the notification?

Answer (score 1):

This might work since I have had success in installing play services in one of my devices.

Go to the Google Play link of the [Play Services App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms) and install the app to your device of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the notification that says that you need to install or update Google Play Services opens up the Play Store with Google Play Services as selected app. From here, you can install/update Google Play Services.