# adb-shell : /sbin/sh: command: not found

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, clockworkmod-recovery, ad-hoc-networks

I've managed to root Google Nexus 7 (2013 Wi-Fi) and now I have **CyanogenMod 10.2-20130919-NIGHTY-grouper** running on it and **Clockworkmod recovery v6.0.1.9** following [this guide](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_maguro).

Then I downloaded and installed **Thinktube image-file** to allow ad-hoc networking.

**I am now able to create ad-hoc network in my tablet** (not yet tested with other same-model tablets) and I can see the adhoc network from other iOS phones and adnroid 2.1 only. However, I want to make sure that:

does Thinktube image-file actually support OLSR rooting protocol or not ?

if not, **then I am already following [this guide](http://www.olsr.org/?q=olsr_on_android)** to download, install and enable OLSR mode.

**But**, when I am in the Recovery-mode in my tablet, and when i open the adb-shell from my PC, I can list files and browse folders in my tablet normally. But I cannot run any other command on the adb-shell. it always gives me this error:

```
/sbin/sh: "any-command-rather-than-ls-&-cd": not found
```

what is this error ?  what did I do wrong ? and what I should do to fix it?

Comment: What commands have you tried?

Comment: @DanHulme: make .. su (but I understood I don't need to do this because I am already in the superUser account when I am inside the adb-shell).. scan_results  and any other commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike a desktop GNU/Linux system, Android isn't designed for command-line use, so it doesn't come with the full set of command-line programs that a GNU system would have. It only has the most basic commands (like the ones you've already seen working), and Android-specific utilities such as `am`, `pm`, `bmgr`.

You can get access to the basic POSIX commands (such as `less` and `grep`) by installing Busybox. There are several installers for it on Google Play. For any more specialist programs like `make`, you'll need to find an Android port of the particular program and install it.

Comment: I don't have google-play app in my tablet after installing CyanogenMod which means I cann't install Busybox-app.. I don't have even SuperUser-app after unlocking ..

Comment: @Rania-Boy You can install Busybox from another source, or [install Google Play](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/12442) first.

Answer (score 1):

The shell on Android is placed in `/system/bin/sh` instead of the regular `/bin/sh` – I wonder where you’d see `/sbin/sh` which I’ve never encountered in the wild on any Unix (and violates the POSIX standard), but in this place you should just change the script/invocation involved.

Most commands are in the `$PATH` anyway, so calling them with explicit paths is not necessarily needed.

That being said, Android Unix userland is *very* minimal – it didn’t even include a [`cat(1)`](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/cat) implementation until recently – so you may be disappointed a bit.

Some people suggest using [busybox](http://busybox.net/) on it. If you do, make sure to not replace the system shell, as Android’s default [`mksh(1)`](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/mksh) is much more powerful than busybox’ `ash`.

Disclaimer: I’m the [`mksh`](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) maintainer.