# Reinstall uninstalled Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, system-apps

How do I tackle my problem as I have mentioned in the title?

I tried to check many times but I could not install Google Play Store.

I have a Micromax a77 Canvas.

Comment: You may be able to side load the apk for the Google Play Store, http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/12/05/download-latest-google-play-store-4-5-10-with-shared-play-store-activity-iap-indicators-and-more/  get it from here. You may need to flash "gapps" for Jelly Bean from recovery if this doesn't work for you as I'm assuming you are rooted to delete the play store: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1796675

Comment: Maybe check [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575)

Answer (score -1):

It's a default application so simply reset Android.

Go to `Settings > Backup and reset > Factory data reset`

Comment: This would be a last resort, rather than reset the device it is easier to try apk, then flash gapps zip then maybe do a factory reset / reinstall ROM. If the OP has a nandroid backup that is recent that would also be a handy solution.

Comment: I agree with @RossC; this nuclear option should only be used as a last resort when all other methods fail. **Additionally, it might not even work** because a factory reset will only erase `/data` and `/cache` partitions, it typically won't restore the `/system` partition.