# Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 - 2014 Edition (Chinese version)

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I live in China. Just purchased a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 - 2014 Edition (SM-P600) tablet. Since I have other devices that came with Google Play Store, I had no idea that Samsung's wouldn't.

I was wondering, is there a way to get Google Play installed and working on this device? Is it possible to purchase the Samsung/Google version and replace the Samsung/Baidu one that it came with? Or, is there some other workaround for this specific issue? I live in China, and so I don't have many options to buy products designed for Westerners.  Hope someone can offer some assistance. Thanks! ~Anthony

Comment: Not Samsungs fault (their devices usually have it), but AFAIK in China it's a bit tricky to use Google Play (correct me if I'm wrong – you're the one living there). For possible solutions, you might wish to see [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.  Okay, I will correct you. I have multiple devices (smartphones and other tablets) that came with Google Play.  All work fine without any issues.  It's just that some apps, like Facebook are blocked and won't work unless you're using a VPN.  And like most Westerns living here, I have multiple VPN accounts. So, it wouldn't be an issue anyway.  Oh btw, using my VPN, I successfully installed Amazon apps.  Using it, I was able to get most of the things that I needed.  Not the best solution, but it does work.  Thanks again!