# Missing "Google Play"app

Tags: google-play-store

My phone (Nokia XL) did not come with Google Play application. How do i install it (i've already tried with some weird .apk files)? If my phone cant use Google Play can you at least tell me if there is some way i can download the apps on my computer and then send them to my phone through USB.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know much about Nokia XL but I don't think they came with Google PlayStore app. I guess, You can use AndroidPolice to get the .apk file of GooglePlayStore or if you want can also user [Google Play Store](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/google-play-store-5-0-37-apk/) apk file if you want.

Comment: You could try installing the Google Play apk as Peter mentioned (although you mentioned this, did it fail, give an error or what?) or you could use the Amazon app store or an alternative app store on the device if Google Play will not work.

Comment: Don't pirate Google Play.

Comment: @DanHulme what do you mean by "Pirate Google Play"?

Comment: The question is asking about installing Google Play on a phone that's not licensed to run it. That's software piracy.

Comment: Look, i dont want to pirate anything, i just want applications from Google Play. So... I tried with 2 .apk files. Both of them installed normaly, but when i click them nothing happens... not even error. I've tried the .apk from Peter Carlos post... same thing happened. If i cant make Google Play happen for me i think ill use the Amazon store, thanks for the info :)

Comment: @DanHulme that's a very good point, I had forgotten that Google apps/services are closed source. The difference between Android and "Google Licensed Android" are a bit fuzzy sometimes, but any Gapp / service shouldn't be installed on a non licensed device.

Comment: See also: [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Google Play unless your phone has installed the Google Play Services to the /system partition, which is only possible through flashing it. (If you don't have root access).

The .apk of Google Play is only for use with phones installed Google Play Services.

The Play Store is the frontend of the Store, which only shows you information and let you interact with the services.
The Play Services are installed at the /system partition (because they need higher privileges to install and uninstall applications). This is the backend of the Play Store (and other Google apps).

Means:
If you don't have the Play Services installed, the Play Store can't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Although Nokia XL is based on the Android Open Source Project with Nokia's interface layered on top, it does not come with Google services due to Nokia's contract with Microsoft. However, there is a solution though it involves rooting your phone. You will void your warranty or even ruin your phone;try at your own risk. If you want to want to risk it, Google is your friend.
Here is one example http://androidrootcentral.com/root-and-install-playstore-nokia-xseries/

Comment: Whilst this answers the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference (please [edit] your question and do so). Otherwise your question ceases to be helpful in case the link dies.