# How to reinstall Playstore?

Tags: google-play-store, rom-flashing, factory-reset, insufficient-memory, apk

Do you have any Idea to reinstall Playstore?
Do I need to Flash it?
Do I need to reset factory?
Do I need to download apk?
Can you help me?
Please?
Device:Cloudfone 700d tv
I don't know how to reinstall this
I install apk version result: Google play has stopped
I install modded playstore: not enough memory

Comment: You can install it as an APK. Google search latest Google Play store. AndroidPolice.com is a safe, reputable site that will have it.

Comment: @RossC I very much doubt that. Might work to *update*, but not for a "fresh install" (as it requires permissions only granted to system apps). See: [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575)

Comment: @Izzy but to delete it in the first place you'd need root access so you can reinstall it surely? I can on my phone here

Comment: @RossC To *delete* it you'll definitely need root, as it's a system app. While in order to simply *update* it, it should be enough to "uninstall updates" and wait for it to update again.

Answer (score 2):

Have you actually deleted it, or only disabled it?  Go into Settings > Apps, page over to 'All', and see whether Google Play Store (and Google Play services) aren't still there on the list; if they are, go in and re-enable them.