# How to install Google Apps And Services on Lollipop AOSP ROM?

Tags: google-play-store, custom-roms, vanilla-android

I have a Lollipop AOSP ROM without any Google related service (Google Play is missing also).

To get Google Play working it seems(but I'm not sure) that I need to install:

- Google Play apk
- Google Services apk
- Google Services Framework
- Google Login Service

I have also read that I have to convert them into system apps. My device is rooted so it should not be too difficult to convert these apps into system apps, but I have no idea of where I could find the updated version of the needed files. I have only found some tutorial for old kindle devices with an older OS.

Could someone help me to find updated version of needed files for Lollipop 5.1?

Any other solution is welcome.

Comment: See: [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575) and our [google-apps tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-apps/info) :)

Comment: The best of Google, right on your devices: https://www.android.com/gms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't install all the APKs individually. Since you've installed an AOSP ROM, what you are looking for is a gapps package that you flash in a similar way to how you flashed your ROM. You can get a minimal gapps package that will install everything you mentioned [here](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95916177934550851).

You need not worry about converting them to system apps. When you flash the package from your recovery, they will be installed as system apps in the system parition.

Comment: That's correct (+1). There are even lists for which version of GApps goes with which Android version. The CyanogenMod wiki has a [page for that](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps). In the past, there was a corresponding page at goo.im – but that site shut down due to financing issues recently. [XDA has a collection](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/gapps-consolidated-gapps-thread-t3064693) as well. I'll update our [google-apps tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-apps/info) a little for that :)

Comment: thank you! I have seen this after that I have posted the message, and works fine

Comment: Open GApps seems like a good place to shop for a GApps package. I'll report back with results.