# How to install google play store on AOSPA 5.1 Falcon?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, motorola-moto-g

My moto G is rooted. I am just about to instal Paranoid Android from a zip file, but then I'll need google applications. I dont want to install a package with stuff that I dont need. I just simply want the google play store and do the installation of apps from there one by one. How do I do that?

Comment: I am no expert, just downloaded Gapps and opened it up. Couldnt you just download the file, Then remove the apps that you dont want it to install? - Edit: I know you said you didnt want too. But I am just wondering, why not just download the gapps, flash it, then remove everything but the play store then download what you want. I highly doubt there is a Gapps file with only the playstore in it. Unless someone is willing to custom make it. Ask around on XDA forums. Might get lucky. Hope you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Please see: [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575) You cannot install "Playstore only", there are dependencies to care for. Watch out for packages with "minimal" or the like in their names, I remember there were some "stripped-down versions" available for devices with "small storage".

Comment: @jer3my One of the things is that I cant find the zip Gapps that I could use with this Moto G. Do you happen to have the link and some info on the default apps?

Comment: @Izzy It looks like I could flash the custom ROM and then the Gapps Pico (that only seems to have really basic things). Right?

Comment: Sounds correct, yes. Pico IMHO is the smallest subset available. Alternatively, take a look at the [NOGAPPS project](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1715375), and just flash *BlankStore* (that's what I use on my Google-free devices, see my [Android without Google](http://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/android-without-google-1) blog series). Still works, though BlankStore is currently unmaintained. Oh: I didn't try it on Lollipop; but if it doesn't work, just remove it and use Pico instead ;)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the info. I was wondering....the Gapp Pico gets flashed via the CWM I have, right? Sorry about the newbie questions. :)

Comment: No prob – and yes, you flash the archive via your custom recovery (CWM, TWRP, or whatever it is). Or you install BlankStore as system app ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to flash `gapps` which provides little except Google Play Services and the Play Store (Gmail, Chrome, Google+, etc. are not included).
http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps