# "Incompatible with other applications(s) using the same shared user ID” while installing Google Play service?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, google-play-services

I know similar question is floating on the same site, but no solution works for me.

I have been using Karbonn A26 Smart phone for the last two years, and I was not able to install run YouTube and Google+ since 2 years. Its hardware is quite ok. It runs Android 4.1.1.

Let me be clear what I am doing:

1. When I install and open YouTube, it says YouTube cannot work without Google Play Services. When I click on **Get Play Services**, it gives me error: "Incompatible with other applications(s) using the same shared user ID".
2. So I factory reset the phone. Then I try it out, same. I can download and install YouTube, but when open it, it keeps saying same "Cannot play without Play Services".
3. Same thing happens when I install and run Google+.

Installing YouTube on clean OS itself does not work.

Do I need to wipe cache? I think factory resetting must also wipe cache. What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: bro they all ask to factory reset. But this does not work for me, neither I am rooted.

Comment: Whether *you* are rooted is a different issue. But what you forgot to mention: Do you have the Google-Apps already installed on your device? Can you e.g. use the Google Play Store app? If not, please see [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575)

Comment: Whether I have Google-apps installed? Well I had only play store installed and it just works. But then I tried installing gmail, Google+, YouTube, all say *Get Google Play Services*, when I click on that, installing Google Play Services fail with above error. Also I checked,  in `Settings > Apps > All`, there is Google Service Framework, is it the Google Play Services?