# Accidentally deleted Google Play Services, now no Google supported app works

Tags: google-play-services, lenovo-a3000

I accidentally deleted Google Play Services after rooting my phone . Now I'm not able to open any Google supported apps , can't open my Gmail. It says:

> Google play service which some of your applications rely on, is not supported by your device. Please contact your manufacturer for assistance.

I downloaded Google Play Services from XDA also but it's not working.

Can anybody tell me how can I can correct this problem? I'm using Lenovo A3000 tablet.

Comment: Try installing google play apk and then convert it to a system app.

Comment: You could try flashing new google apps in recovery.

Comment: Please see: [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575) Note the GApps version must match your Android version. What you've downloaded from XDA (you gave no link, and neither indication what Android version runs on your device) might be the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can install Google Play Services APK, which you can find in the xda-forums. This should normally work.

If nothing else works, you can do a Factory Reset. Unfortunatly, this will delete your Data on the Phone, so i recommend making a Backup.

**EDIT:**

Go to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms with your PC, log in, click install, and choose your phone.

Comment: This won't work as GPS needs to be a system app. Apart from that, it won't work because of, quoting the question: *Now I'm not able to open any Google supported apps*. OP might be able to click the Install button – but without the GPS running, no install would take place on the device (the latter would receive no install notification, as GCM, the GoogleCloudMessaging, is part of the GooglePlayServices). Chicken-and-egg issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely nothing to worry about this issue. All you need to do is the following:

1. Find and Download Google Play Services APK (Pure APK File)
2. Copy the file in your mobile phone memory
3. Click on the APK file that you copied to your smart phone

After some time it will install Google Play Services on your mobile phone.