# Google Play accidentally uninstalled. How to get it back?

Tags: google-play-store

I rooted my phone recently. Then my brother came and uninstalled Google play. I factory reset my phone but the app  didn't come back. How do I get it back?

Comment: @Firelord 1) the device is rooted. 2) the app didn't become visible again after factory-reset. Cetero censo: the app was really removed. // jose: Please see [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem can be found in this XDA link: [Google Play Latest APK](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1996995)

Try pushing it to your system  Give the permissions `644` or `rw- r-- r--`.