# How to install Android from scratch

Tags: google-play-store, installation, google

So I bought a phone from Aliexpress.  It's a J5 Mini phone with Android 4.2.2.  Problem is that it doesn't have Google Play services installed on it.  When I open settings and try to Add Account, nothing happens. I click on the Add Account and it flashes, but that's it.  It looks like I may have to do a clean install of Android on this phone.  Any thoughts how I can do this?

I've downloaded the Android Update.zip file, saved it on a micro SD card to try to side load it, but no luck.  I unzipped the Android update.zip file and tried to install individual apps but the errors I get state that "this installation doesn't support Google Play Services.  I'm assuming because Google Play Services aren't installed. 
[image]

Comment: Related: [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575) // [How do I update Android on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/16575)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that you shouldn't unzip the file.. cause it is a flashable zip.. next, since you said its cause of google play store..

1) go to settings>apps see if any google product is installed already.. If it does, you need to remove it.. If its installed as a user app.. you can uninstall right away in settings.. If it's system app.. Then you need to root your mobile first and download and install any system apps remover..

Note: If you root mobile, your warrenty will be void.. Since you are using samsung, rooting is against their mobile laws..

2) if the google apps are not installed, search google as "4.2.2 gapps" you will get lot of links.. download anyone you want and flash it in recovery..

Note: it is highly recommended to use custom recovery like clockwork mod, philz touch recovery or twrp to flash files.. google it, you will find one if someone ported it for your device..!