# how to install play store on samsung galaxy ace?

Tags: google-apps

How can I install the google play store app on my Samsung galaxy Ace?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please see: [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575) Apart from that, doesn't ship the Galaxy Ace with the Google apps?

Comment: Since it's such an old phone, maybe it has "Android Market" instead, which will update itself to Play Store without any action.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility your phone doesn't have any of the framework apps for google like maps, gmail, etc.  If this is the case then the below will not work and you will have to flash the framework.  The is already question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24768/does-china-mobile-galaxy-s3-model-gt-i-9308-have-google-play-store).  If you have a Chinese edition you might be out of luck

Now if your phone is supposed to have gapps or had google maps and the other framwork apps then try this:

All you need to do is download the APK file [Here](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/) and follow the steps

1. Place the APK file on your SD card
2. Install the APK by finding it on your phone where you saved it and clicking it. This can be done by using a file explorer.  There should be one on your phone.
3. You may need to enable unknown sources by going to Settings ---> privacy and security and toggling the unknown sources setting

Comment: Installing the Play Store as a third-party app will most likely lead to repeated force closes.

Comment: I wish we knew what carrier we were working with. It depends on what is already on his/her phone