# How to install Play Store on Jio Lyf LS 4005?

Tags: google-play-store, rom-flashing, 5.1-lollipop, google-play-services, google-apps

I have recently bought a Jio Lyf 4005 which has Android 5.1 Lollipop running. But it does not have Google Play Store, instead it has Lyf Store (provided by the ISP) which has only a few apps available. Is there any way I can install Google Play Store on it?

I have already tried following and failed:

- Downloading and installing Google Accounts Manager, Play Store and Google Play Services APKs. It keeps showing the message "Unfortunately, Google Play Services has stopped." When I try to open Google Play Store it shows the "Cannot Connect to the Server [RH-01]".
- I have rooted the phone and tried to copy GApps files to system folder but I am unable to paste anything there.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please see our [google-apps tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-apps/info), which has some instructions on this. After reading that, also follow up to [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575)

Comment: I have finally figured it out. You can install Play Store on Flame 6. See this blog entry and follow steps: https://tanninpower.wordpress.com/2016/10/28/how-to-install-google-play-store-on-reliance-jio-lyf-flame-6-ls-4005/

Comment: Be welcome to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) with the details you've found! As a link might die, please make sure to directly include the basics. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation on this site! Can you un-protect it?

Comment: Seeing the amount of spammy/low-quality answers we've already had to remove here, I'd prefer not to. You're only lacking 2 points. A single accepted edit would suffice, be it a question/answer here or a tag wiki. Feel free to ping me in chat to approve the edit, so we can speed up things ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have figured out how to do this. To install Play Store on Lyf Flame 6 follow these steps:
Download required APKs and play_store.zip files from TanninPower.

1. Download required APKs and *play_store.zip* files from [TanninPower](https://tanninpower.wordpress.com/2016/10/28/how-to-install-google-play-store-on-reliance-jio-lyf-flame-6-ls-4005/), put them on your phone.
2. Install KingoRoot and root your device.
3. Install SuperSU
4. Uninstall KingoRoot
5. Install Flash Fire, load *play_store.zip* file in it and flash it. It may take some time and phone will restart after it.

Play Store should now be installed. You can uninstall SuperSU and FlashFire, it will not affect Play Store installation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have done so much. Seems like they have cut the server connection between Google PlayStore and they use their OS. Only possible thing for you to do is flash a custom rom. To do it,

1. install Clockworkmod or TWRP mod.
2. Find an appropriate Custom Rom made for your phone.
3. then install Gapps if they dont have it.

all the best

Comment: I have tried searching for custom ROMs for this phone. Do you think that custom ROMs can be available for such phones? Can I use some other phone's ROM on this one?

Comment: @DDC No, ROMs are device specific. Is there custom recovery for your device (TWRP or CWM)? If so, backup and move the backup to a safe location, then flash a basic gapps package from opengapps.org