# How Install Google Play Store In Samsung J3 Pro Korean Set?

Tags: google-play-store, samsung, google-play-services

Recently I bought Samsung J3 Pro Korean set. There is no Google Play Store in Samsung J3 Pro Korean set. When i install applications, This message interrupts

```
This App Relies on Google Play Services
```

When i install Google Play Services following message interrupts

```
Unfortunately Google Play Services Has Been Stopped
```

Can anyone tell me how to install Google Play Store in Samsung J3 Pro Korean Set. Do i have to buy other phone that supports Google Play Store.

Is there any way to allow Google Play Store In it?

My Country: `pakistan`

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You might want to check this [http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-apps/info] and this [http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device]

Answer (score 1):

The google play store comes pre-installed in all the Samsung Phones.

However, phones locked to some network operators will have the Google Play app stored in a folder named Google.

To move Google Play out of the Google folder, simply touch the folder to open it, press and hold on Google Play and then drag Google Play out of the folder on to the home screen.

If you still can't find the Play Store you might have disabled it mistakenly while deleting trash data.

Follow the below steps to check whether the Play Store has been disabled, and enable it:

1. Go to the "Settings"
2. Scroll down and tap on "Application Manager"
3. Choose DISABLED OR All apps, followed by Disabled
4. Scroll down to find Google Play Store and tap on it.
5. Tap Enable

This would resolve your problem.

Comment: Note: also some non-locked phones also have all google products in one folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of injecting the Google Play services, but you will need to install a custom recovery. I recommend TWRP.

- Download the following files:

  1. Samsung ADB Drivers. Install them.
  2. TWRP Recovery image for your phone (Samsung J3)
  3. ODIN Flashing utility
  4. An OpenGApps package of your choice. Make sure the processor architecture and Android version is correct. - http://opengapps.org/
- Put your phone into Download Mode and start ODIN. To put your phone into Download mode, turn off your phone then turn it on again pressing a few of the physical buttons (usually holding the power button and volume up at the same time). This puts you into the bootloader menu, and you use the Vol Up and Down keys to select Download mode.
- On the AP tab in ODIN, select your TWRP image and hit 'Start'
- Do the whole bootloader menu thing again, but this time select Recovery.
- When TWRP loads up, put the OpenGApps package onto your device the same way you would any file in any other given situation. Once it is fully copied, select 'Install', install from zip, find the OpenGApps zip package (if you get lost, try to look for /sdcard/) and swipe to install.
- Reboot the device.It may take a few minutes and will bring you through a Google setup screen.

Comment: Are you sure this works?

Comment: I do this all the time with custom ROMs (which similarly do not bundle Google Play applications due to legal reasons)