# Unfortunately, Google Play services has stopped?

Tags: google-play-store, kernel

I recently bough an Android computer from China. However, it does not have Google Play Store on it. I've tried downloading and installing the Google Play APK. The installation appears to be successful, but it freezes each time that I try to open it, with a message saying "Unfortunately, Google Play services has stopped" The system has Android Version 6.0.1 and Kernel version 3.10.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Naturally, you cannot simply install Playstore as user app. First, it needs to be a system app, and second it depends on several other Google apps (GSF, Google Services Framework – see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play_Services)). For details, please check with our [google-play-store tag-wiki](/tags/google-play-store/info) and especially follow up to [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/27808/16575)

Alternatively, you could e.g. use the the [YalpStore](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.github.yeriomin.yalpstore/) app (and optionally the [microG framework](https://microg.org/), an open-source GSF alternative – not really needed by *YalpStore* but would provide the needed services for other apps usually depending on GSF).

Comment: I have downloaded Yalp Store successfully. It seems to be working, but I'm unable to log in into one of the software I downloaded.

Do you know what this means...

"Not allowed to start service intent [act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER
pkg=com.google.android.gms(has extras)] without permission
com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"

I get this when I try to log in into a Point Of Sale software I downloaded through your Yalp Store.

I'll appreciate your insight.

Comment: That app obviously requires GCM (Google Cloud Messaging), which is only available via Google Apps or microG. See second paragraph of my answer and follow the link.